# I am not getting how to concatenate two Linked List

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am not getting how to run the concatenate function using both Node and LinkedList as classes. If anyone knows how to do it, please let me know.

Here I have created two classes one for linked list and the former one for Node creation.
Using create function and passing array as Linked list input. Also, I am getting the headref using getHead() and getHead2() functions which give the starting pointer of first and second Linked List respectively.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node{
    public:
    int data;
    Node* next;
    
    Node(){
        data=0;
        next=NULL;
    }
    Node(int data){
        this->data=data;
        this->next=NULL;
    }
};

class LL{
    Node* first, *second;
    public:
    LL(){
        first=second=NULL;
    }
    
    void create(int arr[], int n){
        Node* t, *last;
        first=new Node();
        first->data= arr[0];
        first->next=NULL;
        last=first;
        
        for(int i=1;i<n;i++){
            t=new Node();
            t->data=arr[i];
            t->next=NULL;
            last->next=t;
            last=t;
        }
    }

    void create2(int arr[], int n){
        Node* t, *last;
        second=new Node();
        second->data= arr[0];
        second->next=NULL;
        last=second;
        
        for(int i=1;i<n;i++){
            t=new Node();
            t->data=arr[i];
            t->next=NULL;
            last->next=t;
            last=t;
        }
    }
    
    Node* getHead(){
        return first;
    }

    Node* getHead2(){
        return second;
    }
    
    void display(Node* p){
        while(p){
            cout<<p->data<<" ";
            p=p->next;
        }
        cout<<endl;
    } 
void concatLL(){
        Node* p=first;
        while(p->next){
            p=p->next;
        } 
        p->next=second;
        second=NULL;
    }

};

int main()
{
    LL l,l2;
    int arr[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
    int arr2[]={2,5,7,8,9};
    int n=sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    int n2=sizeof(arr2)/sizeof(arr2[0]);
    l.create(arr,n);
    l2.create2(arr2,n2);
    cout<<"Displaying first LL"<<endl;
    l.display(l.getHead());
    cout<<"Displaying second LL"<<endl;
    l2.display(l2.getHead2());

    cout<<"Displaying Linked list after concatination"<<endl;
    l.concatLL();
    l.display(l.getHead());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hello! I think you misunderstood something. Your LL class should not contain "first" and "second", it should just have one Node pointer, usually named "head". Also the concatenate function should take a second LL as argument, i.e. void concatLL(LL *other)

Comment: can you correct the code for me?

Comment: Based on the answer below, something like this, but you need to rewrite the LL class also void concatLL(LL *other){
        Node *p=head;
        while (p->next)
            p=p->next;
        p->next=other->head;
    }

Answer (score 2):

p is equal to NULL when executing `p->next=second;` in concatLL() causing undefined behaviour since the while loop runs until p == NULL. You should use while(p->next) instead of while(p) and check that first is not a null pointer before.

Comment: But that too isn't solving my question completely. Actually, earlier I was doing using struct but now when I am changing all of this to classes, then I am not sure how to perform all of these. Please let me know the complete answer.

Comment: Don't count on someone giving a "complete answer", because it is counter-productive. You don't learn coding unless you try to solve it yourself. The best for you is to get just enough hints to be able to move forward.

Comment: concatLL() requires that the lists to concatenate are stored in LL object, the method is called on. But in the code shown above one list is stored in the object "l" and the other list is stored in the object "l2". Calling concatLL() on the object "l" concatenates the first list with an empty list, because the second list is stored in "l2". To get your code working you should create both lists in one LL object and call concatLL() on that object.

Comment: @Fomas Thank you for helping me to solve this problem....this is what I am making error there... at first I am trying to do something else then did something else.

Answer (score 0):

A linked list is still a Node, and as others said, at the end of your while loop p is pointed to NULL. You can't `NULL->second=second` neither `NULL=second`, so change your while loop stop condition:

```cpp
void concatLL(){
        Node* p=first;
        while(p->next){
            p=p->next;
        } 
        p->next=second;
        second=NULL;
    }

};
```

Here is my solution:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Node {
    Node* next;
    int value;

    Node(int value) {
        this->value = value;
        this->next = NULL;
    }

    Node(int n, int a[]) {
        value = a[0];
        next = NULL;
        Node* p = this;
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            p->next = new Node(a[i]);
            p = p->next;
        }
    }

    void concat(Node* head) {
        Node* p = this;
        while (p->next != NULL) {
            p = p->next;
        }
        p->next = head;
    }

    void display() {
        Node* current = this;
        while (current != nullptr) {
            cout << current->value << " ";
            current = current->next;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int b[] = { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    Node* list1 = new Node(5, a);
    Node* list2 = new Node(5, b);
    list1->display();
    list2->display();
    list1->concat(list2);
    list1->display();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is what I am asking, I want to do this problem using classes only, not structure. Using Structure, I have done the same.

Comment: A linked list is not a node. A linked list has nodes. It is a "has a" relation, not a  "is a" relation

Comment: Thank you for correcting me! A linked list has nodes and is expressed by a Node pointer, is that correct ?

Comment: @SandeshSingh struct isn't different much from struct: it don't have accessibility modifiers and features of OOP, which are things you won't use in this problem. The problem is not because of Class, it is your original code